# Mostrar o resultado ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho esse botão, mas quando clico esse exibe o value, e não o que é digitado.

```
<input type="text" id = "numero"/>
<input type="submit" id = "adivinhar" value = "Clique aqui"/>

<script>

    var AcessarElemento = document.getElementById("adivinhar");
    AcessarElemento.onclick = botaoClicado;

    function botaoClicado() {
        alert(AcessarElemento.value);
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está exibindo o valor do próprio botão clicado quando faz `AcessarElemento.value`, você precisa selecionar o campo `<input type="text" id = "numero"/>` pelo seu id, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
//Seleciona o botão pelo id
var AcessarElemento = document.getElementById("adivinhar");
AcessarElemento.onclick = botaoClicado;
//seleciona o input que contém o valor que deseja exibir
Numero = document.getElementById("numero");
function botaoClicado() {
  //exibe o valor do campo
  alert(Numero.value);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id = "numero"/>
<input type="submit" id = "adivinhar" value = "Clique aqui"/>
```